# Arduino Uno & NFC Shield

Tags: arduino, nfc, arduino-uno

I'm trying to establish a connection between NFC shield and arduino uno. I'm using seeedstudio nfc shield v2.0.

I've uploaded all the required libraries. However, when I tried this code snippet;

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include "PN532_SPI.h"
#include "PN532.h"
#include "NfcAdapter.h"

PN532_SPI interface(SPI, 10); // create a PN532 SPI interface with the SPI CS terminal located at digital pin 10
NfcAdapter nfc = NfcAdapter(interface); // create an NFC adapter object

void setup(void) {
    Serial.begin(115200); // begin serial communication
    Serial.println("NDEF Reader");
    nfc.begin(); // begin NFC communication
}

void loop(void) {

Serial.println("\nScan an NFC tag\n");

if (nfc.tagPresent()) // Do an NFC scan to see if an NFC tag is present
{
    NfcTag tag = nfc.read(); // read the NFC tag into an object, nfc.read() returns an NfcTag object.
    tag.print(); // prints the NFC tags type, UID, and NDEF message (if available)
}
   delay(500); // wait half a second (500ms) before scanning again (you may increment or decrement the wait time)
}
```

I got an error message:

NDEF Reader
Didn't find PN53x board

Does anyone have any idea about my problem? What should I do?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

PN53x board is NFC Reader, it can't be read by other NFC Reader(such as Phone).
NFC have two mode: Reader and Tag. 
Tag can be read by Reader.

So use PN53x board to read a nfc tag.